# How To get the current page number in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am generating the pdf report using the mpdf and library , i wanted to get the current page number so that i can get the current page number while iam generating the pdf.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to a main mPDF class:

```
function getPageCount() {
    return count($this->pages);
}
```

and use something like this:

```
$PageCount = $this->getPageCount();
```