# How can I get the current page number in mPDF v7?

Tags: mpdf

I want to change something on the page for multi-page documents, depending on which page number is currently being assembled. As I loop through the items being output, is there a way to check the current page number programmatically? (I do not want to simply print the current page in the PDF.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To get the current page number in mpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043126/how-to-get-the-current-page-number-in-mpdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
$mpdf = new Mpdf\Mpdf();
$pageNumber = count($mpdf->pages);
```

But the `$pages` property of the object is internal and access to it may be disabled in future versions.